# Inputmask prevent oncleared

Tags: javascript, jquery-inputmask

I have this code:

```
$(document).delegate("input", "focus", function (e) {
   $("input").inputmask("1239999", oncleared: function () {}});     
});
```

In `<input type='text' id='input' value="123" />` I have default `value=123` after load page. 
When I try to clear all textbox, I can't clear this part `"123"` because it is a static mask, but after I lose focus, textbox get cleared and I'm sad. I try to use

```
oncleared: function () {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                },
```

but it didn't work. 
Can someone make me happy and keep this value in textbox forever?

Comment: Can you show us your full code example? HTML and Javascript

Comment: @KodieGrantham editing my first post

Comment: Can you tell me which input mask jquery plugin you are using?

Comment: @KodieGrantham, thank you for participating, but i already resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve my problem by using `clearMaskOnLostFocus: false` option:

```
$(document).delegate("input", "focus", function (e) {
   $("input").inputmask("1239999", clearMaskOnLostFocus: false});     
});
```